# replicate server side processing in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to build a query that can handle server side processing from a data table.

For example, my query is:

```
select * from orders where order_id like '%ama%'
or order_number like '%ama%'
or order_test like '%ama%';
```

The idea is that as someone is typing characters into the search bar, the back-end will fire a query and bring search results back to the front-end based on these characters being typed.

What would be an efficient way to perform server side processing with an SQL query?

Here is an example of the filtering that I am trying to understand (https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

If you look under filtering, you would see:

```
$sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
```

Comment: How many records exist in `orders`? Which indexes are defined? Is the call being made locally? There are far more details required to provide an accurate answer. Wildcard searches are expensive though, so it's almost certainly not the most efficient way of dealing with your proble,

Comment: Patterns that start with `%` produce expensive queries. You don't want to fire such a query for every character that is typed in the UI.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to replicate? That query already does the search, are you asking how to execute it every time the user types a character in the search field? Use AJAX to send the search field to the server, and then perform the query.

Comment: @BenM about 500 orders exist. just an index on order_id. The table contains order_id, order_date, order_number, and order_test

Comment: If you have 500 rows, don't worry about performance.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question. I'm looking for help to understand how I could make the search more efficient when processing a search character by character as the user is typing something

Comment: You could just return all the data to the client and put it into an array, then do the searching in JavaScript rather than on the server. 500 items isn't too much to send to the client.